# nginx not serving requests to external IP address

Tags: nginx, ip, ip-address

I have nginx running on port 81. I can telnet using `telnet 127.0.0.1 81` and everything is fine.

But when I try to telnet to my machine from my Mac (an external IP address), I just get this error:

```
telnet: connect to address 109.123.x.x: Connection refused
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host
```

Here is my /etc/nginx/sites-available/default file:

```
server {
        listen   81; ## listen for ipv4; this line is default and implied
        #listen   [::]:80 default ipv6only=on; ## listen for ipv6

        root /usr/share/nginx/www;
        index index.html index.htm;

        # Make site accessible from http://localhost/
        server_name 109.123.x.x;

        location / {
                # First attempt to serve request as file, then
                # as directory, then fall back to index.html
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
        }
        ...
```

I've opened Ubuntu Firewall (ufw) to allow port 81.

I'm totally stuck now.

Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You have server name as

```
server_name 109.123.x.x;
```

This is wrong !!!!!

Put any name not number like

```
server_name mywebsite.home;
```

and put mywebsite.home as the IP of the nginx server in your host file(/etc/hosts) i.e in your mac like in format

```
109.123.X.X mywebsite.home
```

where X.X gets replaced with numbers

or

If you want to serve all the request , simply put

```
server_name _;
```

If that does not solve the things , check below

It's either your firewall i.e iptables blocking your traffic or you have your nginx listening only at localhost i.e 127.0.0.1

Disable firewall

```
sudo ufw disable
```

Check the listening address for port 81

```
sudo netstat -tulpn
```

Comment: I switched to port 8080 and it's working now. Might be something to do with a priviliged port or maybe my 3G connection blocks port 81. Anyway, it's working now. Many thanks for your help.

Comment: If its an instance in the cloud like rackspace or AWS, check your Security Groups. By default port 22 and 80 are the only ones usually open.

Comment: the `sudo ufw disable` did it for me.

Comment: According to the [nginx doc](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html), **using ip address has server_name is not wrong**. _"If someone makes a request using an IP address instead of a server name, the “Host” request header field will contain the IP address and the request can be handled using the IP address as the server name":_

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem a few months ago when I was trying to run ngnix on my Ubuntu system and access the services from another Windows system. I was not able to access any port service like http://127.0.0.1/8000
but after some time, I fixed this by turning off the firewall on my Ubuntu system.

Command to turn off the firewall:

```
sudo ufw disable
```

You can also check the status of your firewall first:

```
sudo ufw status
```

Comment: The firewall was the problem for me too. In my case (on Fedora 32) I used systemctl stop firewalld to check it.

Answer (score 0):

Tips which helped me:
A.)Port forward
B.)Set the public IP as server_name
These steps worked for me especially tip A.)

Comment: Server name should never really be an IP.